# Handling 404 in MVC Core API Project

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to figure out where I went wrong. I want to catch 404 errors that come to my api. I have the middleware setup, but the exception never occurs when I try to hit the page that doesn't exist.

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    try
    {
        await _requestDelegate.Invoke(context);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        await HandleExceptionAsync(context, exception);
    }
}


//in startup
app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandler>();
```

and I register it in the startup, its the first thing I do to ensure it handles the rest.

Comment: 404 is not an exception.  You get a response but the status code is 404.  You have to handle the error by checking the status code.

Comment: @jdweng where would I do that? Do you have a code example I can look at?

Comment: You need to check the context status property the throw an exception.  The code can be any place where you have access to the response.

Comment: @jdweng are you saying I have to write a middleware that checks if response is 404? Then return a custom response? That just feels wrong...

Comment: Did you read the information associated to this?  You don't have to write your own middleware handler its built it... You just need to set it up so that it responds, then you want to trap the specifics you have to get a little lower level on it with the request.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.2#configure-a-custom-exception-handling-page reference this and the items relative to MVC

Comment: @mvermef Read that page many times, I see nothing about 404's specifically and it appears to me it targets MVC Websites, not API. Routing works differently there and can easily capture a 404. I'm confused with how 404's are captured by the core framework in an API project. I want to intercept it and do something with that before sending it back. If you have a concrete example, it would help explain things a lot better. I appreciate the help!

Comment: So you want to capture the 404 at the server and not the client?  You would have to modify the response.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want `UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute` to catch the 404 and modify the response, log, ect.

```
//Startup.cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error/", "?statusCode={0}");
    ...
}

//SomeController.cs
public IActionResult Error(int? statusCode = null)
{
    if(statusCode == 404) return new ObjectResult(new { message = "404 - Not Found" });
    ...
}
```

Comment: Your example did not work for me, however, the following did: `app.UseStatusCodePages(async context =>
            {
                context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                await context.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync("{\"result:\" \"Not Found\"}");
            });` While this will return every type as a 404, I think that is ok as its an api and thers only ever few status codes I'm willing to show. I can now change it to target those status codes.

Comment: What didn't work? I've used this pattern before for apis and you can modify the response to return what you need.